# /usr/sbin/installer fails to install, but gui based installer.app succeeds

Tags: mac-osx

This is only affecting a subset of machines, and isn't affected by the presence of MDM profiles. At least if they are removed the issue persist.

There are many Google search results for errors related to:

```
Install rejected with error: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain 
Code=100 "Authorization is required to install the packages."
```

However none of the suggestion have worked.

These are the logs I have found. My Question is:

How do I interpret these logs, where do I look to start troubleshooting this?

- 2024-01-29 installd[1605]: PackageKit: request (at * PKTrustLevelAppleDeveloperID) not compatible with right(s) system.install.apple-software, system.install.software.iap
- 2024-01-29 installd[1605]: PackageKit: Install rejected with error: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=100 "Authorization is required to install the packages."
- 2024-01-29 installer[5492]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=100 "Authorization is required to install the packages." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Authorization is required to install the packages.}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs indicate that authDB related rights are at fault. In this particular case the DB entry related to the installer was modified by some unknown process.

```
security authorizationDB read system.install.software
```

On the affected machine revealed that the status of a key `Allow-Root` was set to false

After testing the command on a working machine, it was found this value is equal to true.

Updating the authorization to allow root has resolved the issue.

Powershell Solution:

```perl
security authorizationdb read system.install.software | 
plutil -convert json -o - - | ConvertFrom-Json | 
foreach {$_."allow-root" = $true ; $_} | ConvertTo-Json | 
plutil -convert xml1 -o - - | 
security authorizationdb write system.install.software
```

Although if you are experiencing a similar problem, the rights or rules for the authorization entry could be modified in a different way that is preventing the installer from working.

Useful Links: https://theevilbit.github.io/posts/macos_authorization/